# How do I divide Laurent polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, wavelets

I have an example from a paper (listed below) that I cannot figure out. I can divide normal polynomials, but the alternative ways to divide Laurent polynomials is beyond me at the moment. The paper lists two polynomials, and three possible quotient/remainder pairs. The polynomials are,

\begin{equation}
a(z) = z^{-1} + 6 + z, \quad b(z) = 4 + 4z,
\end{equation}

and the three sets of quotients and remainders are,

\begin{equation}
q(z) = \frac{1}{4}(z^{-1} + 5) , \quad r(z) = -4z,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
q(z) = \frac{1}{4}(z^{-1} + 1), \quad r(z) = 4,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
q(z) = \frac{1}{4}(5z^{-1} + 1), \quad r(z) = -4z^{-1}.
\end{equation}

I understand how to obtain the last quotient and remainder, but I do not understand how the first two were obtained. A worked example of one or the other would be fantastic, thanks. This is from the [Daubechies and Sweldens paper on factoring wavelet transforms](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.106.8124&rank=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the order in which you try to eliminate the terms. If you start with the $z^{-1}$ term, you can get rid of it by $\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}b(z)$ and you are left with

$$ a(z)-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}b(z) = 5+z $$

For this polynomial you can again chose which one you want to eliminate with a fitting multiple of $b(z)$.

Eliminating the $5$
$$ a(z)-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}b(z)-\frac{5}{4}b(z) = -4z = r(z) $$

eliminating the $z$
$$ a(z)-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}b(z)-\frac{1}{4}b(z) = 4 = r(z) $$

Comment: Voila! That does it! Thanks so much!